# Couldn't establish bluetooth connection with phone

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I am able to pair my device but I am not able to connect it. I used the command

```
sudo hcitool cc --role=m <bdaddr>
sudo hcitool cc --ptype=dm1,dh3,dh5,hv1,hv2,hv3 <bdaddr>
```

[image]

I am getting the above output. Can anybody please tell me how to sort this problem?